# What is the best index for this query - if condition?

Tags: mysql

I have a query with multiple if conditions, which means only execute if have the input or data.

Below is the query

```
        var sql = `SELECT 
        COALESCE(commerce_order.total_price_usd, 0) AS 'Total price (USD)',
        commerce_order.country AS Country,
        commerce_order.customer_id AS 'Customer Id',
        COALESCE(commerce_order.ffm_status, "unfulfilled") AS 'Fulfillment status'
        FROM commerce_order
        WHERE merchant_id = ?`;
        var bind = [p.data.store_id]
        const fromIndex = sql.indexOf('FROM');

        if (p.data.hasOwnProperty('email')){
            sql += " AND commerce_order.customer_email REGEXP ? "
            bind.push(p.data.email);
        };

        if (p.data.hasOwnProperty('startDate')){
            sql += " AND DATE(commerce_order.processed_at) >= ? "
            bind.push(p.data.startDate);
        };

        if (p.data.hasOwnProperty('endDate')){
            sql += " AND DATE(commerce_order.processed_at) <= ? "
            bind.push(p.data.endDate);
        };

        if (p.data.hasOwnProperty('paymentStatus')){
            if (p.data.paymentStatus !== 'all'){
                sql += " AND commerce_order.financial_status = ? "
                bind.push(p.data.paymentStatus);
            };
        };

        if (p.data.hasOwnProperty('fulfillmentStatus')){
            if (p.data.fulfillmentStatus !== 'all'){
                if (p.data.fulfillmentStatus === 'fulfilled'){
                    sql += " AND commerce_order.ffm_status = ? ";
                    bind.push(p.data.fulfillmentStatus);
                } else if (p.data.fulfillmentStatus === 'unfulfilled'){
                    sql += " AND commerce_order.ffm_status IS NULL "
                };
            };
        };

        if (p.data.hasOwnProperty('order_number')){
            sql += " AND commerce_order.order_number = ? "
            bind.push(p.data.order_number);
        };

        sql += " ORDER BY commerce_order.processed_at "
```

How to make a composite index for this query? Or do I only need single column index? Please advise, thank you.

Comment: We probably can't even give an exact answer based on what you showed above, because the above code shows a query being built dynamically.  Please show us a _single_ SQL query...not some other programming language which builds a query.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That is the reason why I am asking this question. I want to know how to do the index with this kind of query...   If only single query, I would not posting here

Comment: Well then you need to potentially cater to _every_ version of the query which might be output from the code you showed us.

Comment: The thing is that each time your application will execute a single query, but the query will have different filters. This is no different from the situation when a table is referenced by multiple queries with different filter and join conditions by different functions. You need to strike a balance between trying to cover every filtering / ordeting / joining with indexes vs size of the indexes and reduced performance for data modifications. You need to evaluate how frequently certain filtering conditions are used and if adding those to an index helps with þhe speed of the queries.